# Python: Encode/Decode dictionary contains list to/from json

Tags: python, list, dictionary, json

I am developing a REST full service using Tornado. A method of this service encodes result to json which is a dictionary contains a list. I used json.dumps() method. The output would be like this:

```
str: {"msg": "Loaded 2 of 10 records", "data": ["{\"description\": \"Description of first product\", \"title\": \"test\"}", "{\"description\": \"Second description\", \"title\": \"test2\"}"]}
```

At test, I want to decode the above output from string (which is in json format) to python dictionary using json.loads() to test the data, but the list would not decode correctly:

```
dic: {u'msg': 'Loaded 2 of 10 records', u'data': [u'{"description": "Description of first product", "title": "test"}', u'{"description": "Second description", "title": "test2"}']}
```

I the other word, it seems data are not decode recursively as they are encoded. Each list element is still string. One way is to decode the list items again, but isn't there any better and standard solution for decoding encoded data?

Comment: It looks like you `dumps`'d your dict, then `dumps`'d the resulting string. Figure out where that's happening and make your code not do that.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I had an encoder for `SQLAlchemy` objects which make the entity object json. I change it so the encoder now make the alchemy object to dictionary (instead of json) and it fixed. Thanks.